# MAMP won't start Apache/MySQL because httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

I've had some problems with my MAMP the last few days, which until recently work flawless! But today I discovered why and hope someone had the same issue and a solution.

My problem, when I open httpd.conf and remove # to Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf where the are Virtual Hosts are MAMP won't start!

If I don't include it MAMP starts without any problems.

I can't figure this out!

I have uninstalled/reinstalled MAMP, tried older versions before I found the issue but I suspect it will be the same regarding version.

Does anyone here got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

So stupid really, but some of my VirtualHost were written with front / in the address and some with back \ and appearantly you can't have mixed.

Like so:
DocumentRoot "/htdocs/test/test/"
DocumentRoot "\htdocs\test\test\"